# Sum up every x values in a row

Tags: c#, vb.net, linq-to-dataset

I have a column `calendar week` and a column `amount`. Now I want to sum up the amount for every 4 calendar weeks starting from the first calendar week in April. E.g. if I have 52 (rows) calendar weeks in my initial table I would have 13 (rows) weeks in my final table (I talk about table here since I will try to bind the outcome later to a DGV).

I am using Linq-to-dataset and tried different sources to get a hint how to solve this but group by, aggregate couldnt help me but maybe there are some applications of them that I dont understand so I hope one of you Linq-Experts can help me.

Usually I post code but I can just give you the backbone since I have no starting point.

```
_dataset = New Dataset1
_adapter.Fill(_dataset.Table1)
dim query = from dt in _dataset.Table1.AsEnumerable()
```

Comment: What's the value of `calendar week` column? Can you post some sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can group by anything you like. You could, theoretically, use a simple incrementing number for that:

```
var groups = dt
    .Select((row, i) => Tuple.Create(row, i / 4))
    .GroupBy(t => t.Item2);
```

(c# notation)

Then you can calculate the sum for each group:

```
var sums = groups
   .Select(g => g.Sum(t => t.Item1.Amount));
```

You mention you want to start at a certain month, e.g. April. You can skip rows by using `Skip` or `Where`:

```
dt.Skip(12).Select(...)
```

`i` will always start at 0, making sure your first group contains 4 weeks. However, to know exactly how many weeks to skip or where to start you need more calendar information. I presume you have some fields in your rows that mention the corresponding week's start date:

```
dt.Where(row => row.StartDate >= firstOfApril).Select(...)
```

Comment: @Servy, how do you mean that?

Comment: The items are to be grouped on a column value, "Calendar week", not on index.

Comment: Nevermind, I didn't notice what you were doing exactly, your post is actually wrong, not just using superfluous methods.

Comment: @Servy - can you explain exactly what you mean? The OP mentions a dataset with a row for each calendar week, and they want to sum up the amount for every four weeks. So, weeks 0..3 are the first four weeks. `Select((row, i) => Tuple.Create(row, i / 4))` assigns each row a number, ending up in a first group with rows 0..3, etc. Where exactly do you see me err?

Comment: The error is that you should be grouping the rows based on the value of the week column, not based on the item's index in the result set.

Comment: @Servy - I understand the OP's requirement exactly the opposite - he wants to define where to start with counting. Thats what a initial `Skip`/`Where` followed by a select will do. If you take the calendar week's number you might end up with a first group containing less than four weeks. But I reckon we both base our claims on presumptions that we make - the OP might clarify that. I find your judgment and wording a bit rude though given that I proposed almost exactly the same as you did (apart from are different assumptions).

Comment: I hope I get that right. I will find out that week is the first week in April (e.g. this year 15). Now I want to sum 15 to 18, 19-22 and so forth till (not included) the next first week in april. I hope that clarifies a bit.

Comment: @ruedi, OK, then this answer should work out for you.

Comment: @Servy - given ruedi's clarification would you still think that this is not working?

Comment: @chiccodoro Yes.  His comment in no way indicates that he wants to be using the index of the row as the value of the week instead of the column value that he has stated represents his the week number.

Answer (score 1):

Divide the week by four (using integer division to truncate the result) to generate a value that you can group on.

Comment: even in that case, if the values are different then how will you group them? I believe you are talking about SQL `group by`

Comment: @Rahul The act of dividing the weeks by four result in each of the first four weeks, each of the fourth through eights weeks, etc. to have the same value.  You can group on that value using `GroupBy`, as you said you have already tried doing.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the hint! What I did now is I added Group By CWeek = (dt.week / 4) Into Total = Sum(dt.amount) . All that changes is that the weeks change from (1 -> 0.25, 2->0.5 etc). Could you maybe give me another push?

Comment: @ruedi As I said, you need to perform integer division so that the results are truncated to an integer.  If the week is not currently an integer, you should turn it into one.

Answer (score 0):

first convert the data into a lookup with the month and then the amount. Note your columns need to be called `CalendarWeek` and `Amount`. Then convert to a dictionary and sum the values per key:

```
var grouped = dt.AsEnumerable().ToLookup(o => Math.Ceiling((double) o.Field<int>("CalendarWeek")/4), o => o.Field<double>("Amount"));

var results = grouped.ToDictionary(result => result.Key, result => result.Sum());
```